# What is the underlying mechanism behind va_list and where is it defined?

Tags: c, data-structures, variables, data-types

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/ 
According to the above link, `va_list` is an argument or parameter used in some macros - `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`. These macros are present in the `stdarg.h` file.

I know that `va_list` can hold multiple values but what kind of an entity is `va_list`? My question is what is the underlying mechanism behind `va_list`? How is it able to hold multiple values? (For example, an array can hold multiple values and the mechanism behind it is multiple memory locations referenced by subscript values. Array is a predefined data structure present in C.)

My second question is where is `va_list` defined?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know that it is used as a parameter for the macros in  <cstdarg> but what exactly is this entity. And where is it defined?

Comment: @gnat I will edit the question.

Comment: @gnat I have edited the question to make it clearer. Please take off the [hold] from the question.

Comment: It's defined in `stdarg.h`  There are many places on the Internet where you can view the source; here's one: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/stdarg.h

Answer (score 11):

The answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure

> The va_list type is an array containing a single element of one
>   structure containing the necessary information to implement the va_arg
>   macro. The C deﬁnition of va_list type is given in ﬁgure below

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int gp_offset;
   unsigned int fp_offset;
   void *overflow_arg_area;
   void *reg_save_area;
} va_list[1];
```

`va_list` is defined in `stdarg.h` as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/ states.

You can refer to the book ["The Standard C Library" by Plauger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131315099) if you need to know the ins and outs of the std libc.

Answer (score 1):

See also the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification and the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for your target platform. For x86-64/Linux, read the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) supplement (see also the [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage).

Several aspects of `<stdarg.h>` are built in the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. thru `__builtin_va_start`,  `__builtin_va_arg`, etc...) and `<stdarg.h>` is provided by the compiler. See also its [__builtin_va_arg_pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fva_005farg_005fpack-2703), etc...

You might also be interested by [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) (e.g. if you want to dynamically build a call to a variadic function).

Answer (score 0):

va_list generally does not store the values, it merely refers to them.

In the old days (and I believe still today on x86-32), parameters were passed on the stack. va_list was a simple pointer, pointer arithmetic would be used to move va_list through the arguments on the stack.

Many architectures nowadays pass parameters in registers. In some cases it may be possible to simply push the registers onto the stack and then iterate through them as before, but in more complex cases where different types of parameter can be placed in different types of register this is not possible. So va_list is often a more complex structured type to keep track of the different types of parameter.